# consecutive timestamp simulator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to generate a consecutive timestamp in node JS in a 1-second period. something similar to

```
var timeStamp = "2017-04-17T18:48:03.608Z"

for (int i=0; i< 1000000; i++) {
      timeStamp = // increase in 1 second
      console.log(timeStamp);        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a date object, and use [`Date.prototype.setSeconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds) to add a second:

```js
var timeStamp = "2017-04-17T18:48:03.608Z";

var time = new Date(timeStamp);

time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 1);

console.log(time.toISOString());
```

Use [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to convert it back into the original format, you provided it in.